# Haskell monad bool repeat

Tags: haskell, monads

Sorry if I couldn't make a better title. I'm trying to work with monads in Haskell but i'm having a little trouble.

So, what I should do is:

**Define the function**

**`repeat:: IO Bool -> IO () -> IO()`**

**So that `repeat test oper` has the effect of repeating `oper` until the condition `test` is `True`**

So, I did this:

```
repeat:: IO Bool -> IO () -> IO()
repeat test oper
    = do res <- test
            if res 
            then return ()
                else do oper
                    repeat test oper
```

But this code isn't working. Could you explain me why?
Now i'm receiving a "parse error on input if". I guess this is just a syntax error, but I still don't know how to solve this exercise.

Comment: You would be correct that this is just indentation. Instead of asking for a fish, why not [learn how to fish](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation)?

Comment: @user2407038 Sadly, that page mentions nothing about the danger of using tabs, which is particularly bad for SO questions (SO converts tab indents to 4 spaces, Haskell defines them as 8).  Although that doesn't seem to be the whole problem in this case. (At least, I can find no tab width that makes the question code align properly.)

Comment: Use the `-fwarn-tabs` option with GHC, or (better) put the `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fwarn-tabs #-}` pragma at the top of your source file (before any module imports or other real code). This will make the compiler generate a warning if it sees any tabs. Personally I prefer to enable all warnings and then disable the silly name shadowing one.

Comment: @dfeuer My worry here is not about how to handle it myself (I have just configured my editor not to insert tabs), but how to deal with the fact SO mangles tabs in question code in such a way that it may cause indentation errors to be hidden with no evidence tabs were ever used (if the questioner uses SO's tab width 4) or falsely introduced (if they use Haskell's tab width 8).

Comment: @dfeuer After checking, I just realized I *can* find out if tabs were used - if I open the edit page for the question. So the evidence is not completely gone, but it requires knowing to look for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know nesting in haskell is done by using whitespace. Format your code properly and it will work. Remember to use spaces instead of tabs in haskell, as tabs often lead to *weird* parse errors.

```
repeat :: IO Bool -> IO () -> IO()
repeat test oper
    = do res <- test
         if res 
         then return ()
         else do oper
                 repeat test oper
```

Comment: Instead of having all of these do blocks: `repeat b x = b >>= flip unless (x >> repeat b x)`

Comment: You should probably mention that using tab characters is a bad idea; use spaces only to preserve your sanity.

Comment: I've never had parse errors from using tabs in Haskell, but I stopped using them because the `:list` command in ghci doesn't handle them properly.